# Login systems: what is the benefit of not telling the user which part of the login data is incorrect?

Tags: authentication, passwords

I've noticed that when logging in and inputting the wrong username or password, websites usually tend to hide from you which of these pieces of data is wrong. So for instance, instead of saying "Wrong password", they would only say "Wrong username/password".

I understand that their main goal is to disallow the user to try different passwords for a certain username. However, you can find out if a user exists by simply trying to register to the website with it. Thus this scenario would be possible in any case.

So why not tell the user immediately that the password they inputted is wrong? Is it only because it would make is **easier** to find out if the user exists (and then be able to try to crack the password for it)?

Some clarification on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is just as you said. The more information you provide, the less secure your site becomes. Hackers will try [the top 25 passwords](http://gizmodo.com/the-25-most-popular-passwords-of-2015-were-all-such-id-1753591514) first, and then go from there. I you do not tell them that the user id is incorrect they have no idea where to start.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, you can find out if a user exists by simply trying to register to the website with it.

Not if done correctly.
Signup:
Step 1:  ask for email and password
Step 2:  check email and follow directions within
    if account with entered email already exists...  the email should be something to the effect of "someone has tried to signup to Coolwebsite.com using this email address.  If this was you and you have forgotten your password, click here"

Comment: This is actually brilliant. It completely eliminates the possibility of finding out whether or not a user already exists, as you can only proceed with the registration by clicking the link sent to your email. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

If strong passwords are used (enforced), the password is usually harder to guess than the username.

Not knowing which part of the credentials is wrong, makes it **much** harder to guess both.

But, there are cases where this does not help much. E.g. when the username is equal to the user's e-mail address.

So, the only reason for not telling is to make it harder to guess. But it also is a valuable reason. Even when there is no rule that covers all cases.

Comment: not telling also prevents the "attacker" from knowing if the user actually exists...   if the login is email based..   this can also make phishing and social engineering attacks harder to achieve.

Comment: @BradKent But surely (even in an email-based login system) you can easily find out if a user exists, simply by trying to register with it. And if so, like I originally said, the only reason to hide the information of what went wrong at the login stage is to make it harder (or simply longer?) for the cracker to crack a certain user's password.

Comment: @LiranH   simply trying to register with the email should only reveal if the user exists if you have access to that email address.  (see my answer regarding this)

Comment: At least it takes some time to try if a username exists. Also a system can let a user fill out a full form and send it before he/she is told that the username already is in use. It also makes it harder for robots to brute-force tries. But, of course: it just makes it harder, nothing more.